# jQuery - bind multiple events and exclude other events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a search form that has both `<input type="text">` and `<select>` form elements. Listening in to that form I've got this jQuery...

```
$('#searchform :input').stop().on('keyup change',function(){
    // do some ajax stuff
})
```

The tricksy bit is the way the script listens for multiple events using `.on('keyup change' etc.)`. This works great but there's a problem...

When the input fields lose focus the script jquery listener is triggered.

Here's a demonstration to explain what I mean https://jsfiddle.net/o2k4jf90/1/

I want to do something like this...

```
$('#searchform :input').stop().on('keyup change not:blur',function(){
    // do some ajax stuff
})
```

...but clearly that's nonsense. What can I do?

Comment: It's the `change` handler that's causing that as it only fires when the element loses focus. Remove that and it'll work as you expect.

Comment: try removing the 'change' event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try substituting `input` event for `change` , `keyup` events

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(':input').on('input',function(e) {
        $('#report').append('stuff happened<br />');
    })
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/o2k4jf90/3/

Comment: Ooh - spot on! Much more succinct and doesn't require that I significantly rebuild my function. Good work.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because the `change` event fires when an `input` field loses focus, and when the chosen option of a `select` is modified. To achieve what you need, you would need to bind the events separately. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').keyup(stuffHappened);
    $('select').change(stuffHappened);
})

function stuffHappened() {
    $('#report').append('stuff happened<br />');
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/o2k4jf90/2/)

You can still use a single event handler if you hook the event to the `form`, however you would need to check the `type` and `target.tagName` of the event to achieve the same logic, which is not pretty at all:

```
$('form').on('keyup change', function(e) {
    if ((e.type == 'change' && e.target.tagName == 'SELECT') 
        || (e.type == 'keyup' && e.target.tagName == 'INPUT')) {
        $('#report').append('stuff happened<br />');
    }
});
```

For this reason, I would suggest using the former method.

Comment: Top answer, and well explained - thanks :) It is a shame to have to bind the events separately -  my listener was so neat and tidy. But needs must! :)